# install latest jenkins version on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I installed jenkins on ubuntu as described here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

But this seems to be a rather old version:  1.424.6+dfsg-1

The latest version, according to http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ is 1.574. The version 1.424 is from 2011. How can I install the newest version?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy jenkins`? Have you tried to do  `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install jenkins`?

Comment: Thanks. The apt-cache policy showed me that the jenkins package was taken from an internal mirror and not from http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ I disabled the internal mirrors and set the http_proxy, I removed all the old stuff, and then I got the latest version 1.574 with apt-get install jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

To test it out:

1. Make sure Java works (if you can reach the Jenkins you installed with apt-get, it does)
2. Remove or at least shut down the Jenkins you installed with apt-get (but leave dependencies, like Java!)
3. Download the `jenkins.war` of desired version to a location of your choice, such as `/home/desireduser/jenkins/`
4. Set environment variable: `export JENKINS_HOME=/home/desireduser/jenkins`
5. as *desireduser*, run `cd ~/jenkins ; java -jar jenkins.war`

If you just want to test it out in a secure environment, you can do this with your own account. For shared use, you probably want to create user *jenkins* or something. But the point of above is, simply running Jenkins is very simple. Things get a bit more complicated and platform-dependent only, when you want it to start it automatically, etc.

To install it as daemon, [there are docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon).

---

Alternative way: install with *apt-get*, then just replace the *jenkins.war* file with newer version, and restart the service. Jenkins should take care of updating all the extra files. Disclaimer: I have not actually tested this, so I can't promise it actually works... better take backups of jobs, etc.